# Plnvoke Struct Field that is a char** impossible? Have to use unsafe code

Tags: c#, c++, string, pinvoke, marshalling

We have some unsafe C# code that is leveraging a C dll that setups a huge struct. I think they're insane and want to change it to use PInvoke instead but it has a pointer to a char pointer that is messing me up.  E.g. the native code:

```
struct{
    ...
    char** args;
    int    argCount;
    ...
} NativeStruct;
```

If we weren't marshalling a struct and were just passing arguments to a native method I would simply use:

```
[DllImport("NativeLibrary.dll")]
NativeMethod(ref String args, int argCount);
```

But this:

```
struct{
    String args;
    int argCount;
}
```

just marshals in a char* not a char**.  You're not allowed to use ref/out on the struct field member, no UnmanagedType seems applicable.  It seems impossible short of using unsafe code, is it?

Comment: `char**` typically represents an array of strings. I have almost no experience with marshaling across C# and C, but shouldn't the C#-side code be `string[] args` ? Even if it's *not* an array, you could wrap the struct and simply set/return the first element.

Comment: It's always possible to avoid unsafe code (args would have to be an IntPtr), but it complicates .net code and sometimes requires to do buffer copies (using IntPtrs). So if performance/memory is critical, you have to use unsafe code.